# WebRequest results with "URI prefix is not recognized."

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get WebReguest for the "mms://wms.iskon.hr/Novi20%25radio20%25Djakovo", but instead I get NotSupportedException saying:The "URI prefix is not recognized."
Code I use is pretty simple:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(watchedStream.URL.Trim());
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(uri);
```

Mms scheme is the source of this problem, but I just can't figure out working solution.

Update: 
After some brewing I finally got the response, but I can't get WebResponse(). Now my code generates "502 Bad gateway exception".
This new code:

```
 Uri uri = new Uri(watchedStream.URL.Trim());
 WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("http://" + Dns.GetHostAddresses(uri.DnsSafeHost)[0].ToString() + ":1755");
 WebResponse = wr.GetResponse();
```

Comment: After reading suggested material and my own inquiry, these are my results:
If you want to play with mms and other schemes unsupported in .net use Windows Media Foundation or some of its community  ports to .net.
Phil's suggestion is a challenge for which I don't have enough.
Thanks to both of you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the MMS protocol is not meant (or supported) to be be used as a URI.  It seems that you are supposed to use it as a 'rollover URL'.

See following:

[MMS Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Media_Server)

[Eggheadcafe posting](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29931777/mms-protocol-not-working.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the links, that helped me to realize how narrow was my perspective.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the [MSDN page on WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) and specifically at its' inheritance it looks like this is because WebRequest only supports the file, http and ftp schemes.

Edit: I just did some playing with WebClient to see if it could be coaxed into downloading some data, but it uses WebRequest under the covers so you get the same exception :-( However, there's a comment on the WebClient MSDN page that states that

> By default, the .NET Framework
>   supports URIs that begin with http:,
>   https:, ftp:, and file: scheme
>   identifiers

which we kind of already knew. However there's a comment right above there that states

> WebClient instances can access data
>   with any WebRequest descendant
>   registered with the
>   WebRequest.RegisterPrefix method.

This suggests that you should be able to create a class that implements [IWebRequestCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iwebrequestcreate.aspx), which you can then register to support the mms scheme, then you may be able to get to your data.
[WebRequest.RegisterPrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.registerprefix%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I've done as sugested, but I've it done wrong.
All I get is StackOverflowException :)!

Comment: Writing WebRequest inheritor is not a simple task. As soon as I get something working I'll post it here.
But if anyone has good advice or can share some experience, PLEASE do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WPF MediaElement` in order to check it.

Try this code.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MediaElement me = new MediaElement();
                me.MediaEnded += me_MediaEnded;
                me.MediaFailed += me_MediaFailed;
                me.MediaOpened += me_MediaOpened;

                me.Source = new Uri("mms://95.0.159.131/TRTBELGESEL");

                mainGrid.Children.Add(me);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {   
            }
        }

        void me_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OPENED"); //  It means OK!
        }

        void me_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("FAILED"); // It means that URL is not working
        }

        void me_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ENDED");
   }
    }
```